# React Native not displaying Blank on the iphone screen

Tags: react-native

I am writing a code that displays dishes stored in file as an array. I created MainComponent.js that displays Menu dishes. I also have MenuComponent,js that shows a  that displays list of menuItems in  but when I run the app it shows a BLANK WHITE SCREEN, I am struggling to get past this problem and I would appreciate if anyone out there have any idea why I am getting BLANK SCREEN. Below are all files involved for someone to help me guide. there are no compiling errors on display.I tried ios emulator as well as android both of them show blank screen.

Thank you in advance.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native' ;
import Main from './components/MainComponent' ;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return (
        <Main />
     );
  }
}
```

**MainComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import Menu from './MenuComponent' ;
import { DISHES } from '../shared/dishes' ;

class Main extends Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props);

           this.state = {
               dishes: DISHES
           }
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <Menu dishes={this.state.dihes} />
           )
       }
}
export default Main;
```

**MenuComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react' ;
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native' ;
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements' ;

//import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native' ;

//functional component
function Menu(props) {
       const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
           return (
               <ListItem   
                   key={index}
                   title={item.name}
                   subtitle={item.description}
                   hideChevron={true}
                   leftAvatar={{source: require('./images/uthappizza.png') }}
                      />
           );
       };


       return (
            <FlatList 
                data= {props.dishes}
                renderItem={renderMenuItem}
                keyExtractor={Item => Item.id.toString() }
                />
            )

}



export default Menu;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be missing a `<View>` component to render your sub-components.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Main from './components/MainComponent';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Main />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

Try this to wrap your component tree inside a `<SafeAreaView>` to ensure the components are also rendered inside the "SafeArea" (not covered by "navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars" etc.) https://reactnative.dev/docs/safeareaview

Comment: IT is not working for me, I tried <SafeAreaView> and <View>. I am still stuck, if anybody else any ideas to get around this problem.

Comment: Hmm okay, are your dishes definitely populated?  Try to `console.log(props.dishes)` in your MenuComponent.js

Comment: fadzb thank you so much, I had some mispelling on `<Menu dishes={this.state.dihes} />` and changed that to `<Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />`, there was ***s*** missing, I am surprised that it did not show any compilling errors. I am greatfull for all your help.